# Not adding correct data in a file in C

Tags: c

So, I am trying to take a user input and add it to a file, however when I get to the phone number, I write 123123123, so 9 numbers because thats how phone numbers work where I live. But when I check the file that I put this data into, the number is 123122944 ?? why?

```
char firstName[32];
    char lastName[32];
    long int dateofbirth;
    long int phoneNumber;
    char wantItForFree[3];

printf("Record #%d\n", i);
        printf("Enter first name: ");
        scanf("%s", firstName);
        printf("Enter last name:  ");
        scanf("%s", lastName);
        printf("Enter dateofbirth in YYYYMMDD format:  ");
        scanf("%ld", &dateofbirth);
        printf("Enter phone number in 36XXXXXXXXX format:  ");
        scanf("%ld", &phoneNumber);
        printf("Do you want the vaccination for free:  ");
        scanf("%s", wantItForFree);
        printf("\n");

        
        
        fprintf(file, "%d\t%s\t%s\t%ld\t%ld\t%s\n", i, firstName, lastName, dateofbirth, phoneNumber, wantItForFree);
```

Here is the code. What is happening? btw i declared phoneNumber as a long int.

The input is

```
john 
doe 
20010613 
123123123 
yes
```

and the output is

```
john doe 20010613 123122944 yes
```

Comment: `scanf("%ld", phoneNumber);` -> `scanf("%ld", &phoneNumber);`

Comment: I fixed it but it still outputs it as that number that i said above, not as 123123123. @kaylum

Comment: Then please provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and also the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: i tried to fix the question @kaylum

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right binary? If you have fixed `%ld` then there should not be any problem.

Comment: `char wantItForFree[3];` Buffer is too small. Need 4 bytes to store a 3 character string as C strings have a NUL terminator. So code has buffer overflow resulting in undefined behaviour. Fix that first and re-test. Also, add in another debg print statement to verify you are running the latest code.

Comment: ahh it worked!! thank you so much for the help! i really appreciate it! @kaylum

Comment: Aside: phone number is in general not an integer, it is recommended to use strings to store them. If you insist on an integer, at least use unsigned long long or uint64_t, since long is not guaranteed to be big enough.

Answer (score 0):

At least 2 common mistakes are made in this code.  First, there must always be a maximum field width on a `%s` conversion specifier.  If no maximum field width is given, then `scanf` is no better than `gets`.  Secondly, it is always necessary check the value returned by scanf.  If `scanf` does not successfully match the conversion specifier, then no data is written to the corresponding argument.  If the corresponding argument is uninitialized, subsequent reads from that variable result in undefined behavior.  eg:

```
char firstName[32];
if( scanf("%31s", firstName) != 1 ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

A 3rd common mistake made here is the attempt to store a 3 character string in an array of size 3, but IMO that is a secondary error which would be resolved by fixing the 2 primary errors.